# Modify an element inside a cds view

Tags: abap, cds

I want to modify an element inside a cds view in order to change the way it is displayed. I tried using virtual elements and it works fine if I take the data from a separate element (storing the original data) and put it into a new virtual element.

However I cannot figure out how to modify the element itself without displaying an redundant one in my table.
If I try to hide the original one, the data is not loaded correctly. If I try to make the original element virtual it loses it's own data.

What is the correct way to achieve what I want?

Comment: What is your use case? can you just build another CDS view on top of that view with additional display logic for that element?

Comment: @Allen No, unfortunately not. The modification of the elements requires ABAP code, the cds modification functions are not enough

Comment: One way you can provide UI.hidden: true annotation for your original element.

Comment: @Allen When you hide the element through this annotation, the virtual element doesn't receive data. The original element has to be displayed..

Comment: You could try SET_FIELD_CONTROL for the original element in your mpc_ext to hide the element in front end. https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/EmTech/SAP+Annotations+for+OData+Version+2.0#SAPAnnotationsforODataVersion2.0-Property_field_controlAttributesap:field-control

Comment: @Allen I cannot edit the mpc_ext because the OData service is auto-generated (at lease I do not find it). However, isn't the field control the same as setting UI.hidden: true in the backend?

Comment: If you are using virtual elements, I believe you use RDS to expose your CDS views as virtual elements are SADL implemented. UI.hidden is to exclude the field from RDS mapping.

Comment: @Allen I modified the mpc_ext but I am not sure how to set the field control. I tried something like this: `lo_procstatus = lo_entity_type->get_property( iv_property_name = 'procstatus').
    lo_procstatus_annotation = lo_procstatus->/iwbep/if_mgw_odata_annotatabl~create_annotation( iv_annotation_namespace = /iwbep/if_mgw_med_odata_types=>gc_sap_namespace ).
    lo_procstatus->set_field_control( '0' ).`

Comment: Hello, is it working? if not, try lo_procstatus_annotation->add(
       iv_key   = 'field-control'
       iv_value = '0' ).

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work, I get the following error: `HTTP request failed404,Not Found,{"error":{"code":...,"message":{"lang":"en","value":"Resource not found for the segment '0'."}`

Comment: How  do you want to modify it? Give the sample and give your CDS

Answer (score 0):

I just did my own testing regarding how to exclude your original column on `SmartTable`. Below is working on my testing demo.

To exclude your original column from showing in the Column tab of Table setting dialog, there is an [annotation](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/smart-table/#removing-columns) `sap:visible = false`.

Redefine the `Define` method of your mpc_ext:

```
data: 
lo_entity_type type ref to /iwbep/if_mgw_odata_entity_typ,
lo_property    type ref to /iwbep/if_mgw_odata_property,
lo_annotation  type ref to /iwbep/if_mgw_odata_annotation.

super->define( ).

lo_entity_type = model->get_entity_type( 'YOUR_ENTITY_TYPE' ).

lo_property = lo_entity_type->get_property( 'YOUR_ORIGINAL_COLUMN' ) .

lo_annotation = lo_property->/iwbep/if_mgw_odata_annotatabl~create_annotation( /iwbep/if_mgw_med_odata_types=>gc_sap_namespace ).
lo_annotation->add(
    iv_key    = 'visible'
    iv_value  = 'false'
).
```

Comment: I tried this before but my virtual elements don't receive data anymore when I use this approach to hide the original elements

Comment: Hello, i just double checked. I have both the sap:visible annotation and data. There is something you missed?